# Persistent Google API Authorization for Client app

Tags: google-oauth

I'm trying to develop a frontend application that let the user connect with his google account and consumme Google API in the name of that user.

But I'm struggling with Google API. My problem is that if I use the [javascript client library from google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow?hl=fr#js-client-library) I have to ask again for user consent everytime (every hour or everytime the user leaves and come back). Google documentation says "The user must be present to call Google APIs, your app uses only access tokens, and does not require refresh tokens." ([implicit flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis?hl=fr#identify_your_authorization_flow)). I also found other threads that are saying that it's not possible with client side application. ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73448702/persistent-client-only-google-api-authorization))

Do you have any recommendation of a proper way allow me to call google api without providing a bad user experience ? I really can't ask for consent all the time. Am I forced to develop a backend to do that ?